# OpenMP tasks & data environment

Tags: c++, task, openmp

I'm trying to use a task construct for my C++/OpenMP program:

```
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        typename ClusterNormal<DIM>::VectorMean ResultMeanThread;
        ResultMeanThread.setZero();
        #pragma omp single
        for(list<unsigned int>::const_iterator it=IDLeft.cbegin(); it!=IDLeft.cend(); it++)
        {
            #pragma omp task
            {
                ResultMeanThread += Data[*it];
            }
        }
}
```

This code is computing the sum of some `VectorMean` (it doesn't mind what they are, but they have operator + defined) for the elements of data indicated in IDLeft.

Every thread initialize `VectorMean` with all zeros. My problem is that after the for loop, `ResultMeanThread` is still composted of all zeros.

When a task is executed, the sum is computed correctly, but after the task execution,`ResultMeanThread` is always re-initialised to zeros.

How could I fix it? I'm using tasks because of the lists, but my code isn't working.

Comment: shouldn't `ResultMeanThread` be declared before parallel region and marked as a shared variable? also, is it safe to apply `+=` operation in parallel to an object of type `VectorMean`?

Comment: I've created `ResultMeanThread` to be private for each thread. I think that using += operator with a shared variable isn't a good idea because of race conditions...

Comment: After this code, there's a sum of `ResultmeanThread` with single construct

Comment: can you show what happens later?

Comment: This program is for statistical computing, the function simlpy computes mean of some vectors. So I have vectors of all zeros like output

Comment: you said there is a `single` construct afterwards, would you mind showing it?

Comment: Answer found. Thanks for help: error was in considering `ResultMeanThread` private, like you posted in your first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the problem was the declaration of `ResultMeanThread` like private variable.
I tried this code, declaring a vector of `ResultMeanThread` like shared variable (length of vector is nember of threads) so every thread access only one element of the vector (no race conditions).

In the previous code, every `ResultMeanThread` was zero because of `task` construct. Every time that a `task` is executed, private variables are set to their initial value. I have to use `task` construct because of `list`

Here's the code:

```
vector<typename ClusterNormal<DIM>::VectorMean> ResultMeanThread;
typename ClusterNormal<DIM>::VectorMean ResultMeanFinal;

//here i set initial values to zero, and number of vector elements equal to total number of threads

#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    for(list<unsigned int>::const_iterator it=IDLeft.cbegin(); it!=IDLeft.cend(); it++)
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {
            ResultMeanThread[omp_get_thread_num()] += Data[*it];
        }
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait

    // Final sum
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        ResultMeanFinal+=ResultMeanThread[omp_get_thread_num()];
    }
}
```